# First program with scraping, lists, string manipulation

Tags: python, html, parsing

I wanted to find out which states and cities the USA hockey team was from, but I didn't want to manually count from the roster site [here](http://olympics.usahockey.com/page/show/1067902-roster).

I'm really interested to see if someone has a more elegant way to do what I've done (which feels like glue and duct tape) for future purposes. I read about 12 different Stack Overflow questions to get here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import urllib2

url='http://olympics.usahockey.com/page/show/1067902-roster'
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())


locations = []
city = []
state = []

counter = 0
tables = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "dataTable" })
for table in tables:
    rows = table.findAll("tr")
    for row in rows:
        entries = row.findAll("td")
        for entry in entries:
            counter = counter + 1
            if counter == 7:
                locations.append(entry.get_text().encode('ascii'))
        counter = 0


for i in locations:
    splitter = i.split(", ")
    city.append(splitter[0])
    state.append(splitter[1])

print Counter(state)
print Counter(city)
```

I essentially did a three tier loop for `table->tr->td`, and then used a counter to grab the 7th column and added it to a list. Then I iterated through the list splitting the first word to one list, and the second word to a second list. Then ran it through Counter to print the cities and states. I get a hunch this could be done a lot simpler, curious for opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to get the `n`-th column from a bunch of tables on the page, in that case, there's no need to iterate through all the `find_all()` results, just use list indexing:

```
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    myList.append(row.find_all('td')[n])
```

This is also a good use case for generators because you are iterating over the same set of data several times. Here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
import urllib2

url = 'http://olympics.usahockey.com/page/show/1067902-roster'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

def get_table_column(table, n):
    rows = (row.find_all("td") for row in table.find_all("tr"))
    return (cells[n-1] for cells in rows)

tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="dataTable")
column = chain.from_iterable(get_table_column(table, 7) for table in tables)
city, state = zip(*(cell.get_text().encode('ascii').split(', ') for cell in column))

print Counter(state)
print Counter(city)
```

While this works, it also might be a good idea to anticipate possible errors and validate your data:

To anticipate cases where not all rows have `n>=7` `td` elements, we would change the last line in `get_table_column` to:

```
return (cells[n-1] for cells in rows if len(cells) >= n)
```

We should also anticipate cases where the cell contents does not contain a comma. Let's expand the line where we split on a comma:

```
splits = (cell.get_text().encode('ascii').split(',') for cell in column)
city, state = zip(*(split for split in splits if len(split) == 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

- You can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in order not to play with `counter`.

  ```
  for counter,entry in enumerate(entries):
      if counter == 6:
          locations.append(entry.get_text().encode('ascii'))
  ```
- `states` and `cities` would probably be a better name for collections of states/cities.
- You can use unpacking when splitting the string

For instance :

```
for i in locations:
   city, state = i.split(", ")
   cities.append(city)
   states.append(state)
```

- You don't need to store locations in a list and then iterate over the locations, you can handle them directly without storing them.

This is pretty much what my code is like at this stage :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import urllib2

url='http://olympics.usahockey.com/page/show/1067902-roster'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

cities = []
states = []

for table in soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "dataTable" }):
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        for counter,entry in enumerate(row.findAll("td")):
            if counter == 6:
                city, state = entry.get_text().encode('ascii').split(", ")
                cities.append(city)
                states.append(state)

print Counter(states)
print Counter(cities)
```

Now, because of the way American cities are named, it might be worth counting the cities keeping their state into account (because [Portand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland,_Oregon) and [Portland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland,_Maine) are not quite the same city). Thus, it might be worth storing information about city and state as a tuple.

This is how I'd do it :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import urllib2

url='http://olympics.usahockey.com/page/show/1067902-roster'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

cities = []
for table in soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "dataTable" }):
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        for counter,entry in enumerate(row.findAll("td")):
            if counter == 6:
                city, state = entry.get_text().encode('ascii').split(", ")
                cities.append((state,city))

print Counter(cities)
print Counter(state for state,city in cities)
```

Also, something I have forgotten but might be useful to you is to use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) if all you want is to count elements.

```
from collections import defaultdict

url='http://olympics.usahockey.com/page/show/1067902-roster'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

cities = defaultdict(int)
for table in soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "dataTable" }):
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        for counter,entry in enumerate(row.findAll("td")):
            if counter == 6:
                city, state = entry.get_text().encode('ascii').split(", ")
                cities[state,city] += 1
```

Comment: The unpacking is what I was looking for, that makes much more sense.